# pandas count of rows for every combination of columns for one hot encoded data

Tags: python, pandas

Thank you so much for answering this :)
I have a pandas data frame where we have one hot encoded information about whether a customer has a certain product or not

```
customer revenue  P1    P2  P3
Customer1   $1     1    0   0
Customer2   $2     1    1   0
Customer3   $3     0    1   1
Customer4   $4     1    1   1
Customer5   $5     1    0   0
```

for customer1 revenue is $1 and it has products P1 only,
similarly, customer4 has all products

I want to transform this data to show all possible combinations of the products and the count of customers that have those combinations, like so

```
combinations    Count of Customers  Sum of revenue  
P1 only          2                       $6         ---> c1+c5
P2 only         
P3 only         
P1+P2+P3         1                       $4         ---> c4
P1+P2            1                       $2         ---> c2
P1+P3           
P2+P3            1                       $3         ---> c3
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

I believe The combinations of products can be checked like this

```
import itertools
li=df.columns.to_list()
del(li[0:2])
list(itertools.combinations(li, 2))+list(itertools.combinations(li, 1))+list(itertools.combinations(li, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to revert the operation of `get_dummies` (or `OneHotEncoder`) to get a unique combination of products per customer to be able to group and aggregate:

```
# Generate labels P1, P2, P3, P1+P2, ...
cols = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']
labels = ['+'.join(c) for i in range(len(cols)) for c in combinations(cols, i+1)]

df1 = df.assign(R=df['revenue'].str.strip('$').astype(int),
                P=df[cols].mul(2 ** np.arange(len(cols))).sum(axis=1)) \
        .groupby('P').agg(**{'Sum of revenue': ('R', 'sum'),
                             'Count of customers': ('customer', 'nunique')}) \
        .assign(Product=lambda x: x.index.map(dict(zip(range(1, len(labels)+1), labels)))) \
        .set_index('Product').reindex(labels, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(df1)

# Output
    Product  Sum of revenue  Count of customers
0        P1               6                   2
1        P2               0                   0
2        P3               2                   1
3     P1+P2               0                   0
4     P1+P3               0                   0
5     P2+P3               3                   1
6  P1+P2+P3               4                   1
```

For each unique combination, you assign a label:

```
# P1=1, P2=2, P3=4 (power of 2) so P1+P3=1+4=5
>>> dict(zip(range(1, len(labels)+1), labels))
{1: 'P1',
 2: 'P2',
 3: 'P3',
 4: 'P1+P2',
 5: 'P1+P3',
 6: 'P2+P3',
 7: 'P1+P2+P3'}
```

Detail about reverting the `get_dummies` operation:

```
>>> df[cols].mul(2 ** np.arange(len(cols))).sum(axis=1)
0    1  # P1 only
1    3  # P3 only
2    6  # P2+P3
3    7  # P1+P2+P3
4    1  # P1 only
dtype: int64
```

**Update**

> Can you guide me with how to return the name of customers for each combination ?

```
df1 = df.assign(R=df['revenue'].str.strip('$').astype(int),
                P=df[cols].mul(2 ** np.arange(len(cols))).sum(axis=1)) \
        .groupby('P').agg(**{'Sum of revenue': ('R', 'sum'),
                             'Count of customers': ('customer', 'nunique'),
                             'Customers': ('customer', ', '.join)}) \
        .assign(Product=lambda x: x.index.map(dict(zip(range(1, len(labels)+1), labels)))) \
        .set_index('Product').reindex(labels, fill_value=0).reset_index() \
        .replace({'Customers': {0: ''}})

print(df1)

# Output
    Product  Sum of revenue  Count of customers             Customers
0        P1               6                   2  Customer1, Customer5
1        P2               0                   0                      
2        P3               2                   1             Customer2
3     P1+P2               0                   0                      
4     P1+P3               0                   0                      
5     P2+P3               3                   1             Customer3
6  P1+P2+P3               4                   1             Customer4
```

Comment: Does is solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks! @ Corralien it does.
Can you guide me with how to return the name of customers for each combination ?

Comment: Do you want to return a list or a formatted string like "Customer1, Customer5"? I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
In [2692]: from itertools import product

In [2673]: x = df.pivot(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'], 'customer', 'revenue')
In [2661]: ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(set(range(2)),repeat = 3)), names=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])

In [2688]: s = pd.DataFrame(index=ix)

In [2681]: output = s.join(x).sum(1).to_frame('Sum of revenue')
In [2686]: output['Count of Customers'] = s.join(x).count(1)

In [2687]: output
Out[2687]: 
          Sum of revenue  Count of Customers
P1 P2 P3                                    
0  0  0              0.0                   0
      1              0.0                   0
   1  0              0.0                   0
      1              3.0                   1
1  0  0              6.0                   2
      1              0.0                   0
   1  0              2.0                   1
      1              4.0                   1
```

Comment: can i know what `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(set(range(2)),repeat = 3)), names=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])` is doing?  `product` looks like an undefined keyword

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami. `product` comes from `itertools` module. Use `itertools.product` in your case instead.

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami I forgot to add the import statement in the answer. I've updated. Please lemme know if it works for you?

Comment: Thanks!
 @MayankPorwal this gives me a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape on the df pivot line

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami Please upgrade your pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using one-hot encoding, let's try to solve this problem using binary masks:

```py
# Extract the product columns
cols = df.columns[2:]

# Make a bitmask for each column.
#  1 = b001 -> P1
#  2 = b010 -> P2
#  4 = b100 -> P3
bitmask = np.power(2, np.arange(len(cols)))

# Generate the label for each possible combination of products
# 0 = b000 -> Nothing
# 1 = b001 -> P1
# 2 = b010 -> P2
# 3 = b011 -> P1 + P2
# ...
# 7 = b111 -> P1 + P2 + P3
labels = np.array([
    " + ".join(cols[np.bitwise_and(bitmask, i) != 0])
    for i in range(2 ** len(cols))
])
labels[0] = "Nothing"

# Assign each row in the df to a group based on the
# product combination (P1, P1 + P2, etc.)
# Using numpy broadcasting to multiply the product list
# with the bitmask:
#   df[cols]    *  bitmask[None, :]  -> groups
#   P1  P2  P3     
#   1   0   0      1   2   4            1*1 + 0*2 + 0*4 = 1
#   1   1   0      1   2   4            1*1 + 1*2 + 0*4 = 3
#   0   1   1      1   2   4            0*1 + 1*2 + 1*4 = 6
#   1   1   1      1   2   4            ...             = 7
#   1   0   0      1   2   4            ...             = 1
groups = (df[cols].to_numpy() * bitmask[None, :]).sum(axis=1)

# The result
df.groupby(labels[groups]).agg(**{
    "Count of Customers": ("customer", "count"),
    "Sum of Revenue": ("revenue", "sum")
}).reindex(labels, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()[1:]).agg({'P1':'size', 'revenue':"sum"})
my_df.columns = ['Count of Customers ', 'Sum of revenue  ']
```